# Необычное Dropdown с кнопкой

Tags: bootstrap, html, javascript, css

Требуется реализовать такую задумку dropdown меню. Думал кастомизировать из bootsrap.
Какие у кого идеи подскажите?!

[Ссылка на кнопку с выпадающим списком](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_dYv0Q_Y9SLdkNMQUkwalE3aG8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: По-моему кастомизировать dropdown menu из bootstrap'a или сделать по аналогии будет проще всего.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как то так: http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/gZVgT/

единственное с тенью немного "подкрутить" и если нужно чтобы второе открывалось справа->налево то просто UL задать класс с right: 0px;

Answer (score 0):

вот код, при условии, что bootstrap подключен:

HTML

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
     <li class="dropdown" data-toggle="tab">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Йа менюшко<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Действие</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Еще ссылка</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Доп. ссылка</a></li>
             </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Йа второй менюшко<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Действие</a></li>
             </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

JS

```
$('ul.nav-tabs li').click(function(){ $('ul.nav-tabs li').each(function(){$(this).removeClass('active')}); $(this).addClass('active')});
```

итог:

[image]